# Hibernate saveOrUpdate is not persisting completely

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

This Question is related with the code residing [here](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/openmrs/api/db/hibernate/HibernateUserDAO.java)

```
public User saveUser(User user, String password) {

        // this gets as true since this is a new user
        boolean isNewUser = user.getUserId() == null;

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);

        if (isNewUser && password != null) {
            //update the new user with the password
            String salt = Security.getRandomToken();
            String hashedPassword = Security.encodeString(password + salt);

            updateUserPassword(hashedPassword, salt, Context.getAuthenticatedUser().getUserId(), new Date(), user
                    .getUserId());
           // the method is stated below
        }

        return user;
    }


private void updateUserPassword(String newHashedPassword, String salt, Integer changedBy, Date dateChanged,
        Integer userIdToChange) {
    User changeForUser = getUser(userIdToChange);
    if (changeForUser == null) {
        throw new DAOException("Couldn't find user to set password for userId=" + userIdToChange);
    }
    User changedByUser = getUser(changedBy);
    LoginCredential credentials = getLoginCredential(changeForUser);
    // the above method is stated below

    credentials.setUserId(userIdToChange);
    credentials.setHashedPassword(newHashedPassword);
    credentials.setSalt(salt);
    credentials.setChangedBy(changedByUser);
    credentials.setDateChanged(dateChanged);
    credentials.setUuid(changeForUser.getUuid());

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(credentials);

    // reset lockout 
    changeForUser.setUserProperty(OpenmrsConstants.USER_PROPERTY_LOCKOUT_TIMESTAMP, "");
    changeForUser.setUserProperty(OpenmrsConstants.USER_PROPERTY_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS, "0");
    saveUser(changeForUser, null);
}


public LoginCredential getLoginCredential(User user) {
        return (LoginCredential) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(LoginCredential.class, user.getUserId());
    }
```

Hibernate Configurations for [User](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core/blob/master/api/src/main/resources/org/openmrs/api/db/hibernate/User.hbm.xml) And [LoginCredentials](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core/blob/master/api/src/main/resources/org/openmrs/api/db/hibernate/LoginCredential.hbm.xml)

- **LoginCredentials** consists fields that are related to authenticating a user.
- **User** contains fields related to user details.
- **LoginCredentials** & **User** represents a single table.
- When creating a new user, the **saveUser** method is called and when
  `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);` is executed,
  user object gets an **ID**
- Then the execution is passed to **updateUserPassword** to save the LoginCredentials and
  `LoginCredential credentials = getLoginCredential(changeForUser);` is executed.
- But **credentials** gets `null` and causes a null pointer exception.
- If the User object was saved correctly, the credentials object should
  get an object with the user id assigned to it and other fields empty.
- I tried checking for null and manually creating a LoginCredentials object and assigning the user id, but it didn't work.
- Is this a problem that is related to the use of **@Transactional**
  annotation?

Comment: If it's your spring application, have you used @Transactional on any of service or controller methods related to this transaction?

Comment: @svjn: It is OpenMRS. I have pointed the source to git. 
Yes. Transactional annotation is used in DAO calls